# Keyboard shortcut for bullet points in Slack when the special code block handling option is enabled

Tags: keyboard, slack

I send code snippets many times a day over Slack so the following `Enter` options under `Preferences | Advanced | Input Options`  have been quite helpful:

[image]

A downside I have noticed is that `Shift-Command-8` no longer creates bullet points; in fact asterisks also do not generate them.  Is there a workaround?